# Section numbering using letters

Tags: section-titles, alphabet, renewcommand

How can I number sections using letters, starting from a specific letter?

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
```

This will start from the letter A, but I want to start numbering from another letter, e.g. G, H, I, J etc. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `\setcounter{section}{6}`

Answer (score 1):

`\setcounter{section}{6} \section{zzz}` will start from G. Counters are always integers internally, the letter is just the print form.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much!!